# setting url query for modal

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm using image search and display app. Users can click on a photo and a modal would pop up. Those modal would have `id` in the url. However when I refresh the page, the modal isn't there  and an error is shown. I get the url from unsplash api so with page refresh reload the url is gone. How do I Keep the url in url query so that the url persists even on page refresh?

Lisitem

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Link, BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import ModalWrapper from "./ModalWrapper";

const ListItem = ({ photo }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <Router>
        <div key={photo.id} className="grid__item card">
          <div className="card__body">
            <Link to={{ pathname: `/${photo.id}`, state: photo }}>
              <img src={photo.urls.small} alt="" />
            </Link>
            <Route path="/:photoId" component={ModalWrapper} />
          </div>
        </div>
      </Router>
    </>
  );
};
export default ListItem;
```

Modal wrapper

```
import React from "react";
import Modal from "react-modal";
import { useHistory, useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

const customStyles = {
  content: {
    top: "50%",
    left: "50%",
    right: "auto",
    bottom: "auto",
    marginRight: "-50%",
    transform: "translate(-50%, -50%)"
  }
};

Modal.setAppElement("#root");

function ModalWrapper() {
  const history = useHistory();
  const location = useLocation();

  const photo = location.state;

  function downloadImage() {}

  function close() {
    history.push("/");
  }

  return (
    <Modal isOpen={true} onRequestClose={close} style={customStyles}>
      <img src={photo.urls.small} alt="" />

      <div>
        <button onClick={close} className="button">
          Close
        </button>
        <button onClick={downloadImage()}>Download</button>
      </div>
    </Modal>
  );
}

export default ModalWrapper;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why it doesn't work when you refresh the page is because the `photo` that you passed as a param while navigating is no longer available. But, `pathname` is something that's still available (because it's part of the URL itself)

So, on the `ModalWrapper` page, you can check if `photo` is absent, then make a new API call to get the `photo` based on the `id` that is available in the `pathname`. I've never used unsplash API but I think it would be [this API](https://unsplash.com/documentation#get-a-photo).

Your `ModalWrapper` would look like this

```js
function ModalWrapper() {
  const history = useHistory();
  const location = useLocation();
  const [photo, setPhoto] = useState(location.state);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (location.pathname && !location.state) {
      // call the new API here using pathname (photo ID) and setPhoto
      console.log(location.pathname);
    }
  }, [location]);

  function downloadImage() {}

  function close() {
    history.push("/");
  }

  return (
    !!photo && (
      <Modal isOpen={true} onRequestClose={close} style={customStyles}>
        <img src={photo.urls.small} alt="" />

        <div>
          <button onClick={close} className="button">
            Close
          </button>
          <button onClick={downloadImage()}>Download</button>
        </div>
      </Modal>
    )
  );
}
```

---

You haven't asked this but, I would also move the `Router` and `Route` outside the `ListItem` and keep it in `App.js` (wrapping everything in there with Router). Keeping it in `ListItem` is like having a router and route for each list-item, which is not something you would ideally want. You would want to keep one router and route across the application, and it usually belongs to `App.js` or a wrapper or sorts. Here's the [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/nifty-field-804zw) after such changes

Comment: thanks, the error isn't there after the refresh but the modal is also not there when I refresh. Other photos are shown in the grid but when I click on any modal then they dont open in modal cause the url is still the link of the last modal I opened. is it possible that I can still have the modal open after the refresh and be able to close it and open other photo modals

Comment: you told to call the api there. I've used two api in this app, one for just randomly generating photos and one for search api which will be called when the user searches for a term. so in this case, which one should I call?

Comment: @gonnabefireifnohelp you need to call a third API, I've linked it in my answer as well. You can get the photo using the photo ID (pathname)

Comment: I did some changes in the modalWrapper. can you tell if that's the correct way https://codesandbox.io/s/awesome-meadow-vkn4o

Comment: you were close. here, I fixed the issues: https://codesandbox.io/s/hungry-boyd-mek1j